# How to access realtime values of a SSIS Variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Dump all the variables in the ssis package in a text file with current values.
The following code only gets the values of variables that was set during the ssis design.If we run the ssis how can we get the values of the variable at a particular instance during the ssis being executed?

```
 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
            Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(@"D:\Pkg_1.dtsx", null);
            Variables pkgVars = pkg.Variables;

            foreach (Variable pkgVar in pkgVars)
            {
                if (pkgVar.Namespace.ToString() == "User")
                {
                    s = s + pkgVar.Name.ToString() + "=" + pkgVar.Value.ToString() + System .Environment .NewLine ;
                }
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Pkg_1.txt", s);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Dts` class something as follows

```
Dts.Variables["User::VariableName"].Value
```